# How to optimize this process?

Tags: r, function, optimization, sparse-matrix, sapply

I have somewhat of broad question, but I will try to make my intent as clear as possible so that people can make suggestions. I am trying to optimize a process I am doing. Generally, what I am doing is feeding a function a data frame of values and generating a prediction off of operations on specific columns. Basically a custom function that is being used with sapply (code below). What I'm doing is much to large to provide any  meaningful example, so instead I will try to describe the inputs to the process. I know this will restrict how helpful answers can be, but I am interested in any ideas for optimizing the time it takes me to compute a prediction. Currently it is taking me about 10 seconds to generate one prediction (run the sapply for one line of a dataframe).

```
mean_rating <- function(df){
  user<-df$user
  movie<-df$movie
  u_row<-which(U_lookup == user)[1]
  m_row<-which(M_lookup==movie)[1]

  knn_match<- knn_txt[u_row,1:100]

  knn_match1<-as.numeric(unlist(knn_match))

  dfm_test<- dfm[knn_match1,]

  dfm_mov<- dfm_test[,m_row] # row number from DFM associated with the query_movie




  C<-mean(dfm_mov)

}

test<-sapply(1:nrow(probe_test),function(x) mean_rating(probe_test[x,]))
```

Inputs:
dfm is my main data matrix, users in the rows and movies in the columns. Very sparse.

```
> str(dfm)
Formal class 'dgTMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:99072112] 378 1137 1755 1893 2359 3156 3423 4380 5103 6762 ...
  ..@ j       : int [1:99072112] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 480189 17770
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num [1:99072112] 4 5 4 1 4 5 4 5 3 3 ...
  ..@ factors : list()
```

probe_test is my test set, the set I'm trying to predict for. The actual probe test contains approximately 1.4 million rows but I am trying it on a subset first to optimize the time. It is being fed into my function.

```
> str(probe_test)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ X          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ movie      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ user       : int  1027056 1059319 1149588 1283744 1394012 1406595
 $ Rating     : int  3 3 4 3 5 4
 $ Rating_Date: Factor w/ 1929 levels "2000-01-06","2000-01-08",..: 1901 1847 1911 1312 1917 1803
 $ Indicator  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1
```

U_lookup is the lookup I use to convert between user id and the line of the matrix a user is in since we lose user id's when they are converted to a sparse matrix.

```
> str(U_lookup)
'data.frame':   480189 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: int  10 100000 1000004 1000027 1000033 1000035 1000038 1000051 1000053 1000057 ...
```

M_lookup is the lookup I use to convert between movie id and the column of a matrix a movie is in for similar reasons as above.

```
> str(M_lookup)
'data.frame':   17770 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: int  1 10 100 1000 10000 10001 10002 10003 10004 10005 ...
```

knn_text contains the 100 nearest neighbors for all the lines of dfm

```
> str(knn_txt)
'data.frame':   480189 obs. of  200 variables:
```

Thank you for any advice you can provide to me.

Comment: If the code works it's off-topic here. Try posting on [codereview.se].

Comment: You say you can't provide a meaningful example, I'd dispute that. You're looking at your question the wrong way. It doesn't matter what the data is, you just need this function to operate faster. You say this example takes 10s, give a reduced single dataset that takes 0.1s to run (arbitrary number I picked), and ask us how to make it run in 0.001s. With data provided, even a small set, it becomes so much easier for people to help.

Comment: So Chris, if I reword the question to be "How do I convert this R script to Python?", that would seem to satisfy the question guidelines, correct? Then the R script is just an outline of what I'm trying to do in Python.