# How to do a calculation on each line of a pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am brand new to python, I am attempting to convert the function I made in R to Python, R function described here:

[How to optimize this process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51370465/how-to-optimize-this-process)

From my reading it looks like the best way to do this in python would be to use a for loop that would take the following form

```
for line 1 in probe test
 find user in U_lookup
 find movie in M_lookup
 take the value found in U_lookup and retrieve that line number from knn_text
 take the values found in that row of knn_text, and retrieve the line numbers from dfm
 for those line numbers in dfm, retrieve column=U_lookup
 take the average of the non zero values found
 save value into pandas datafame in new column for that line
```

Is this the most efficient (in terms of speed of calculation) way to complete an operation like this? Coming from R so I wasn't sure if there was better functionality for something like this within the pandas package or not.

As a followup, is there an equivalent in python to the function dput() in R? dput essentially provides code to easily share a subset of data for questions like this.

Comment: Google your question first, https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=heFQW4eKAvC80PEPh7e-8AQ&q=How+to+do+a+calculation+on+each+line+of+a+pandas+dataframe+in+python%3F&oq=How+to+do+a+calculation+on+each+line+of+a+pandas+dataframe+in+python%3F&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1.496.496.0.1595.2.1.0.0.0.0.160.160.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.159.0...0.vh0CxzEYvSI

Comment: A loop will almost certainly not be the most efficient method. You probably want `pandas.merge` or just a simple mapping, but you need to create a [mcve] if you want a detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.apply(my_func, axis=1)` to apply the function/calculation to each row of a dataframe.
Where, my_func would contain the required calculations